# Is there any good and easy-to-use module built in Python for editing memory?

Tags: python, python-3.2, memory-editing

Is there any good and easy-to-use module built in Python for editing memory? Or is there any module like this at all?

What I'm looking for is a way to attach to a process and read from/write to it. Much like how Cheat Engine works. [Here's a example of how it works in C++](http://www.mpcforum.com/showthread.php?251308-Tutorial-Basic-C-Game-Hacking-%28Memory-Editing%29).

Comment: What do you mean by memory editing? Whose memory, what kind of memory, and in which ways?

Comment: You might be able to do it using the [`ctypes`](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html) module. Specifically, with the `ctypes.from_address()` function.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8250625/access-memory-address-in-python

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Took me a while to find a way of doing this but here's what I came up with!

```
from ctypes import *
from ctypes.wintypes import *

pid = 0 #the pid of the process, aquired earlier by hand

address = 0x0000 #where to read from while in the memory

OpenProcess = windll.kernel32.OpenProcess
ReadProcessMemory = windll.kernel32.ReadProcessMemory
CloseHandle = windll.kernel32.CloseHandle


PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS = 0x1F0FFF

datadummy = b'.'*200
buffer = c_char_p(datadummy)
bufferSize = len(buffer.value)
bytesRead = c_ulong(0)

processHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, False, int(PID))

ReadProcessMemory(processHandle, address, buffer, bufferSize, byref(bytesRead))

CloseHandle(processHandle)
```

And to write to the memory I would just add `WriteProcessMemory = windll.kernel32.WriteProcessMemory` and then call it

Comment: when i run print(readprocessmemory(...)) it prints 0, i think i should change the 
datadummy = b'.'*200
buffer = c_char_p(datadummy)
bufferSize = len(buffer.value)
bytesRead = c_ulong(0)
 but i have no idea with what..

Comment: @extreme4all ReadProcessMemory writes to the buffer 'buffer' and the returned value is the error code (0 = no error).