# Python - how to get the value at a memory address?

Tags: python, windows, memory, ctypes, cheat-engine

I am trying to make Python get the value/data from an address such as 0x101BFFDC, which I found by using a cheat engine for a game. I've done much research and believe that I need to use `ReadProcessMemory`. However, I have tried several examples without success.

For example, I found the following code:

```
from ctypes import *
from ctypes.wintypes import *
import struct

OpenProcess = windll.kernel32.OpenProcess
ReadProcessMemory = windll.kernel32.ReadProcessMemory
CloseHandle = windll.kernel32.CloseHandle

PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS = 0x1F0FFF

pid = 10684 # pid of the game
address = 0x101BFFDC # I put the address here

buffer = c_char_p(b"The data goes here")
val = c_int()
bufferSize = len(buffer.value)
bytesRead = c_ulong(0)

processHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, False, pid)
if ReadProcessMemory(processHandle, address, buffer, bufferSize, byref(bytesRead)):
    memmove(ctypes.byref(val), buffer, ctypes.sizeof(val))
    print("Success:" + str(val.value))
else:
    print("Failed.")

CloseHandle(processHandle)
```

I expect it to give me the value 56, which is what I get from the cheat engine. However, it just prints "Failed." every time.

How can I get the value right?

Comment: tried this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8250625/access-memory-address-in-python ?

Comment: @sharath that wouldn't work for reading memory from another process, only the Python process.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a ctypes wrapper for WinAPI [`ReadProcessMemory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680553). It takes the process ID, base address, and size in bytes to read. It returns the byte string read from the target process.

If `allow_partial` is false, the entire address range must be readable, else it fails with the Windows error code `ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY`. If `allow_partial` is true, the returned byte string may be less the number of requested bytes.

**ctypes definitions**

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import wintypes

kernel32 = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32', use_last_error=True)

ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY = 0x012B
PROCESS_VM_READ = 0x0010

SIZE_T = ctypes.c_size_t
PSIZE_T = ctypes.POINTER(SIZE_T)

def _check_zero(result, func, args):
    if not result:
        raise ctypes.WinError(ctypes.get_last_error())
    return args

kernel32.OpenProcess.errcheck = _check_zero
kernel32.OpenProcess.restype = wintypes.HANDLE
kernel32.OpenProcess.argtypes = (
    wintypes.DWORD, # _In_ dwDesiredAccess
    wintypes.BOOL,  # _In_ bInheritHandle
    wintypes.DWORD) # _In_ dwProcessId

kernel32.ReadProcessMemory.errcheck = _check_zero
kernel32.ReadProcessMemory.argtypes = (
    wintypes.HANDLE,  # _In_  hProcess
    wintypes.LPCVOID, # _In_  lpBaseAddress
    wintypes.LPVOID,  # _Out_ lpBuffer
    SIZE_T,           # _In_  nSize
    PSIZE_T)          # _Out_ lpNumberOfBytesRead

kernel32.CloseHandle.argtypes = (wintypes.HANDLE,)
```

**function**

```
def read_process_memory(pid, address, size, allow_partial=False):
    buf = (ctypes.c_char * size)()
    nread = SIZE_T()
    hProcess = kernel32.OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_READ, False, pid)
    try:
        kernel32.ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, address, buf, size,
            ctypes.byref(nread))
    except WindowsError as e:
        if not allow_partial or e.winerror != ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY:
            raise
    finally:
        kernel32.CloseHandle(hProcess)
    return buf[:nread.value]
```

**example**

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import os

    buf = ctypes.create_string_buffer(b'eggs and spam')
    pid = os.getpid()
    address = ctypes.addressof(buf)
    size = len(buf.value)

    value = read_process_memory(pid, address, size)
    assert value == buf.value
```