# Read a value from specific memory adress on linux using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need function in python to read a value from a specific memory address on Linux .
I've a PID process and memory address '4df0568'.
i try using ctypes, ptrace.

sample: a int32 value on adress '4df0568' = 3065

i need a loop function to read this address and return a int value.

note: this is a game memory address

EDIT: this a SoLUTION

```
pid = 4563

address=0x4df0568 # top of stack (have a look at /proc/{pid}/maps for the interesting addresses)                                               

    fd = open(f"/proc/{pid}/mem", "rb")
    fd.seek(address)
    value = fd.read(4) # read an int32
    print(int.from_bytes(value, byteorder='little'))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access memory address in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8250625/access-memory-address-in-python)

Comment: thx, but this don't work on external process on linux.

Comment: I see. Python is not really designed around low-level constructs in mind. If you don't find a pure Python way of doing it, I would recommend writing a library in another language and calling it using FFI from python.

Comment: If you're attempting to read a memory location that isn't allocated to your process by the operating system I'm reasonably confident that it isn't possible - modern operating systems don't tend to like software trying to touch memory assigned to other processes.

Comment: i've mistake delete previuos comment, this a solution:    address=0x4df0568 # top of stack (have a look at /proc/{pid}/maps for the interesting addresses)                                               

    fd = open(f"/proc/{pid}/mem", "rb")
    fd.seek(address)
    value = fd.read(4) # read an int32
    print(int.from_bytes(value, byteorder='little'))